# SystemVerilog synthesis in Vivado

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado, synthesis

I am trying to synthesize a SystemVerilog (.sv) file in Vivado. The file uses defines from another Verilog (.v) file. This combination is not working. I tried renaming define file into *.sv then the error got resolved.

Is there such constraint that all defines for SystemVerilog should be in another SystemVerilog file?

If no, what is the best way to resolved this issue? I don't want to rename the file since it is part of release from different team.

Comment: Does the behavioural simulation work? I mean before synthesis.

Comment: `define` macros are depended on compile order and should be indifferent if it is Verilog or SystemVerilog.

Comment: @MituRaj yes. simulation works fine

Answer (score 2):

[Vivado Synthesis Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiixqDY7LXtAhVk4HMBHeojDrEQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0G7uhe4a10ZBBtPHrLbtIX) guide mentions about this issue in page 260:

> ### Targeting SystemVerilog for a Specific File
>
> By default, the Vivado synthesis tool compiles  *.v  files  with the
> Verilog 2005  syntax and *.sv  files with the SystemVerilog syntax. To
> target SystemVerilog for a specific  *.v  file in the Vivado IDE,
> right-click the file, and select  Source  Node  Properties.  In  the
> Source  File  Properties  window,  change  the  File  Type to
> SystemVerilog, and click  OK.
>
> ### TCL Command to Set Properties
>
> Alternatively,  you  can  use  the following  Tcl command  in  the
> Tcl  Console:

> `set_property file_type  SystemVerilog [get_files <filename>.v]`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the way Vivado organizes compilation units between files and files of different languages. Verilog did not have this concept except that each compile command lumped all files into one compilation unit. If you had multiple compile commands, each command is a separate compilation unit, and macro definitions do not cross compilation units.

SystemVerilog adds the capability for each file to be a separate compilation unit regardless of whether the files are on a single command line. This was done because SV has many more constructs besides macros that can be defined in the compilation unit space. Making each file a separate compilation unit is how many other programming languages work and reduces name collisions.

However, his may create backward compatible compiler issues when you mix both languages on the same command line. Each compiler many have different way of addressing this issue. Apparently Vivado creates two separate compilation units by default; one for Verilog and one SystemVerilog. BTW, Questa/Modelsim lumps all Verilog files into a single compilation unit, and each SystemVerilog file into its own compilation unit.

Xilinx created a [short video](https://www.xilinx.com/video/hardware/compilation-units-in-vivado-synthesis.html) about this with details about more options for Vivado.